# Is MVVM Pattern used in Web or in Windows Forms or in Web and Windows Forms?

Tags: winforms, web, design-patterns, mvvm

Is MVVM Pattern used in Web only or in Windows Forms only or in Web and Windows Forms ??

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.